# Python ftp stor freezes

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm having some problems with a script in python to upload some files to a ftp over TLS. I use the following code:

```
ftps = FTP_TLS(FTP_SERVER)
ftps.set_debuglevel(2)
ftps.login(FTP_USER,FTP_PASSWORD)
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.cwd(DIR)
ftps.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(file))
```

At that point the script seems to freeze. If I log on the ftp server through filezilla for example I can see the file created but the size is 0Kb. I'v to cancel the script with Ctrl+C and then the file is showed as the correct size in filezilla. If i let the script to finish the file is deleted on the ftp server.

The debug output is this:

```
*cmd* 'AUTH TLS'
*put* 'AUTH TLS\r\n'
*get* '234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.\r\n'
*resp* '234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.'
*cmd* 'USER XXXXXXXXX'
*put* 'USER XXXXXXXXX\r\n'
*get* '331 Password required\r\n'
*resp* '331 Password required'
*cmd* 'PASS **************'
*put* 'PASS **************\r\n'
*get* '230-congrats\r\n'
*get* '230 User logged in.\r\n'
*resp* '230-congrats\n230 User logged in.'
*cmd* 'PBSZ 0'
*put* 'PBSZ 0\r\n'
*get* '200 PBSZ command successful.\r\n'
*resp* '200 PBSZ command successful.'
*cmd* 'PROT P'
*put* 'PROT P\r\n'
*get* '200 PROT command successful.\r\n'
*resp* '200 PROT command successful.'
*cmd* 'CWD XXXXXXXXX'
*put* 'CWD XXXXXXXXX\r\n'
*get* '250 CWD command successful.\r\n'
*resp* '250 CWD command successful.'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to A.\r\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to A.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX).\r\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (XXXXXXXXXXXX).'
*cmd* 'STOR file.txt'
*put* 'STOR file.txt\r\n'
*get* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.\r\n'
*resp* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.'
^C
*cmd* 'QUIT'
*put* 'QUIT\r\n'
*get* '226 Transfer complete.\r\n'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete.'
```

The script freezes at that point:

```
*resp* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.'
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Could it be a problem of passive configuration ? Maybe you could try to configure with `ftps.set_pasv(False)` before the call to `storlines`

Comment: If I set pasv to False I get that error: ftplib.error_perm: 501 Server cannot accept argument.

Comment: Just to be sure it is not a problem with input file, could you try : `import io
 txtfile = io.StringIO(u"abc\ndefgh\nijkl\n")` and then `ftps.storlines("STOR " + filename, txtfile)`

Comment: same result, hangs here:*get* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.\r\n'
*resp* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

Comment: Do you control the ftpserver and the network to it ? And what server is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could setup a TLS server and use exactly same commands with python 2.7.

All goes fine. I get slight different answers because I think I do not use same server as you do. Things begin to be really different at the `storelines` command (I use a `with` to ensure that file will be closed) :

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    ftps.storlines("STOR foo.txt", fd)


*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to A.\r\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to A.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,56,48,227,80)\r\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,56,48,227,80)'
*cmd* 'STOR foo.txt'
*put* 'STOR foo.txt\r\n'
*get* "150 Opening ASCII mode SSL data connection for 'foo.txt'.\r\n"
*resp* "150 Opening ASCII mode SSL data connection for 'foo.txt'."
*get* '226 Transfer complete.\r\n'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete.'
'226 Transfer complete.'
```

The main difference is that I get a `150 Opening ASCII mode SSL data connection` when you get a `125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.`

My conclusion is that you client script is not the cause since it works on my computer, but either the server FTPD or a problem of network in between (proxies ?). But I don't like the `125 Data connection already open`

EDIT:

I works the same under Python 3.4 but needs to open local file in binary mode :

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
    ftps.storlines("STOR foo.txt", fd)
```

same output ...

Comment: Thanks, I don't have control to the server side but I could speak with them and they changed something and now it works. They use IIS 7.